# How to calculate increase in costs?

Tags: calculus

ChocoCo wants to improve sales of its chocolate bars. The bars are currently 3×8 squares and cost $0.12 in raw materials, and it wants to increase this to 4×10 squares. If an extra 750,000 bars are sold, how much will costs have increased?

`I got 600,000 but I'm not sure of this answer: 
I firstly calculated the cost per square of one bar which is $0.12/(3x8) = $0.05
I then computed the difference in the  total cost of selling 750,000 units of the new chocolate bar versus the old one. That is, 750,000 * (40-24)* 0.05 = $600,000`

Comment: I think you must have the right answer, but the question seems poorly posed.  You have answered the question correctly if $750,000$ bars are sold in total, but the question says this is the number of *extra* bars sold.  In this form, the question is unanswerable, because we don't know how many bars were sold before the change.  We know the cost per bar has gone up $80$ cents, but we don't know how many bars there are.  This must be a mistake in the question, and you have answered as intended, in my opinion.

Comment: You have a mistake in the cost per square, it should be 0.005\$.